# Can I travel to Austria on a new visa-free passport if I lost the passport that contained a long-term Austrian visa?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, passport-renewals, austria, lost-documents

I am a US student who will be studying abroad in Austria and leaving in August. I applied for my visa and it was mailed but FedEx never delivered the package and claims it has no clue where it is.

I am going to apply for a new passport which should come in time if I expedite. However, I am worried I will not have time to get a replacement Austrian visa.

- Will they just send me a new visa, even if I have a new passport with a different number than when I applied the first time?
- Do I have to reapply in person at the Austrian consulate? I'm from Chicago and I really don't want to have to fly to New York to appear in person.

The next open appointment date for the Austrian consulate is after I leave. I've heard the Austrian consulate in NYC is outrageously strict about appointment times. If I call them and plead my case, will they let me come at an earlier date?

Any chance I could just put this off, show up in Austria with my new US passport and apply for a replacement visa before my 90 days is up?

Comment: a) What type of visa/AG? b) Valid until? c) Is this duration enough, or do you plan to get a long(er)-term permission later? d) What university/school? (while the actual name is not really important, it's the most easy way to categorize it)

Comment: @deviantfan D type visa for valid from August 20 to december 23. Program is IES Abroad

Comment: Ok ... a bit tricky. It's night here, but I'll try squeezing some info out of the ministry tomorrow. (If I forget, please don't hesitate to remind me here...)

Comment: ... I did try, but was unable to reach anyone :/ Will try later again...

Comment: Unless someone else experienced this exact situation, my (unhelpful) answer is probably as good as it will get: With the idea that me contacting them would be more effective (more familiar with the land, laws, office procedures and roles...), I did exactly that and got shot down: Apparently, they completely refuse to give generic advice for procedural problems like this. Anything and everything is discussed solely with the applicant. (Seems you were right about the NY consualte being pretty stiff.) Tldr, you need to fight through the bureaucracy alone, sorry.

Comment: First, do you have proof they granted the visa? Collect all the evidence and approach the embassy. I am afraid only they will be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously too late for this poster but here are some details:

**Getting a passport**

Assuming you're American, make an appointment with the [local passport agency](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/where-to-apply/passport-agencies/chicago.html) and make your travel plans clear -  explain that you need your passport ASAP so you can sort out the visa in time. Their site will make clear what supporting documents you need.

**Getting a visa**

Normally, your exchange program would help you resolve this.

Austria differentiates between people intending to stay less than six month, and those staying longer. For stays of less than six months you are required you get a visa, as was done in this case, this [must be done from outside of Austria except when the case is a defined exception](https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/355/Seite.3550010.html).

Since you can't reach the embassy, I'd try calling the hotline at +43 1 531 26 3557 from 8a-12p CET to get more information on if you can be recognized as an exception or what the best process would be.

**Alternatively, if you're staying longer**

If you are actually planning to stay more than six months, Americans under normal circumstances don't need a visa to enter Austria, but you do need legal grounds to stay there for an extended time: a residence permit. I'm American and was directly enrolled in university in Austria. You can show up under the usual visa-free process any tourist would and then apply for a residence permit. You need to apply for the permit before said visa-free tourist time allowance is up. If you apply for the permit before the end of your visa-free time but the processing isn't complete by the time that 90 days is up, you are fine to stay in Austria but you're not allowed to travel to other Schengen countries until you receive your residence card. (Though there are no borders so enforcement is minimal, I wouldn't risk pushing this.) Here's the link on the [government's site](https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/12/Seite.120222.html):

> Folgende weitere Personengruppen können ihren Erstantrag im Inland stellen, wobei auch hier die Antragstellung nicht zur Überschreitung der Dauer des erlaubten visumfreien Aufenthalts berechtigt:
>
> *Additionally, the following groups of people may make their initial application in-country, though this does not allow you to exceed the duration of the permitted visa-free stay:*
>
> Drittstaatsangehörige, die gemäß § 1 Abs 2 lit i oder j AuslBG oder § 1 Z 5, 7 oder 9 AuslBVO vom Anwendungsbereich des AuslBG ausgenommen sind oder die unter § 1 Z 4 Personengruppenverordnung 2014 – PersGV 2014, BGBl. II Nr. 340/2013, fallen [...] oder eine Aufenthaltsbewilligung "Studierende" beantragen, nach rechtmäßiger Einreise und während ihres rechtmäßigen Aufenthalts
>
> *Third country nationals who are excepted from the scope of application  of the AuslBG by § 1 Abs 2 lit i or j AuslBG or § 1 Z 5, 7 or 9 AuslBVO or who fall under § 1 Z 4 Personengruppenverordnung 2014 – PersGV 2014, BGBl. II Nr. 340/2013, and who are applying for [...] a "Student" residence permint following legal entry and stay.*

Have fun in bureaucrat paradise.